# Get max or min value from associative array with function and parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameters

Here is the code as far as I got it right now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="scanarray('a', 'max')">Test with a, max</button>

<button onclick="scanarray('b', 'min')">Test with b, min</button>



<p id="demo">test</p>

<script>



var array = [{"a":1},{"b":3},{"a":6},{"b":10}];


var max = null;
var min = null;
var value = null;

function scanarray(scanval, searchterm) {

  if (array.length < 1) {
    return -1;
  }

    if(searchterm == "max"){

    max = Math.max.apply(Math,array.map(function(e){return e.scanvalue;}))

    }else if (searchterm == "min"){

    min = Math.min.apply(Math,array.map(function(e){return e.scanval;}))

}else
{document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Only max and min available";}

    if(searchterm == "max"){

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Search: " + scanval +"  "+ "Value: " + max;
    }

    if(searchterm == "min"){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Search: " + scanval +"   "+ "Value: " + min;
    }

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The above should give me a and 6 or b and 3 as results. However I get NaN as result for the value part. When using "return e.a" in the Math section and only having a as keys it works.

I want to be able to determin the max or min value of a key I enter as parameter to the function.

Hope you can help me here.

Thanks in advance.

TheVagabond

Comment: `array.map(function(e){return e.scanvalue;})` what's e.scanvalue?

Comment: scanvalue is the key value I scan for here a or b the e is just for the function just bevor it so it is referenced

Comment: The objects in your array don't have properties called `scanvalue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some naming mess in your code. For example `scanvalue` is name of your function but you are trying to reach it as a parameter of e(`e.scanvalue`). I should be `scanval`. But still there are some problems. You can't reach property "a" or "b" of e if `e.scanval`. You're trying to reach *variable of variable*.

Then, you should use `e[scanval]`. It returns you to value of "a" or "b". But if object doesn't have one of them? Then you should add "|| 0" to get correct value. (Instead of NaN or undefined) *It means that; use e[scanval] if its valid, if not use 0.*

Use this;

```
return e[scanval] || 0;
```

> If your boundaries include some negative values, use something like -9999 or -Infinity.

Comment: Thanks that worked great for the max part, however the min part is not working. Do I need to change something there? I get -Infinity but it should be 3 as 3 is the lowest b value.

Comment: It is not programming error.  For minimum part, use +Infinity or something like +99999. Simple logic.

Comment: Not problem but I suggest you that; review this code on your own and understand the logic / structure behind this line: `return e[scanval] || -Infinity;`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting Nan because e.scanvalue returns undefined in your case.

Try using custom function.

```
function getValue(arr){
var res = [];
for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
{

    for(var anItem in arr[j])
    {
        res.push(arr[j][anItem]);
    }
}
return res;
}
```

and call this function like

```
max = Math.max.apply(Math,getValue(array))
```

and

```
min = Math.min.apply(Math,getValue(array))
```

accordingly.
Hope this helps!!!!